# Trouble finding large jumps between data points in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a sigma clipping program that calculates the differences between each point in an array and its neighbor, and if the difference is greater than x times the standard deviation of the array, it sets the neighbor equal to the average of the two points closest to it. For example, if I had an array, `testarray = np.array([1.01, 2.0, 1.22, 1.005, .996, 0.95])`, and wanted to change any points that were more than 2 times deviant from their neighbor, then this function would search through the array and set the 2.0 in the `testarray` equal to `1.115`, the average of 1.01 and 1.22.

```
def sigmaclip2(array, stand):
  originalDeviation = np.std(array)
  differences = np.abs(np.diff(array))
  for i in range(len(differences)):
    if differences[i] > stand*originalDeviation:
        if array[i+1] != array[-1]:
            array[i+1] = (array[i] + array[i+2]) / 2.0
        else:
            array[i+1] = (array[i] + array[i-1]) / 2.0
    else:
        pass
return array
```

This code works for this small `testarray`. But, I am working with a larger data set (~12000 elements). When I try to run it on the larger data set, I get the same array back that I plugged in.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

I should note that I have tried some of Python's built in sigma clipping routines, such as the one from Astropy, but it appears as if that cuts off any values that are greater than x times the standard deviation of the array. This is not what I want to do. I want to find any large, sudden jumps (often caused by 1 bad value) and set that bad value equal to the average of the 2 points around it if the bad value is more than x times the standard deviation discrepant from its neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

in line 6 of your function array[-1] may be a typo as it always uses the last element of the array. Are you missing an i? In which case you might need to shift by one as difference[0] is the diff between array[0] and array[1]

PS I think I would use np.where with slice notation on array to find just the indexes to alter rather than useing a normal python loop. With numpy a loop is almost always a bad idea.

EDIT

Understand about edges but I don't think your code does what you expect. When I run it it averages array[2] to 1.06 as well as array[1] to 1.115

If I change line 6 to `if array[i+1] != array[i-1]:` (array[-1] is the last entry, always 0.95) it still doesn't work properly.

You also have to think about what you want your code to do where you get more than one outlier.. `1.01, 2.0, 2.25, 1.99, 1.22, 1.005, .996, 0.95` To cope with single outliers I would use something like

```
def sigmaclip3(array, stand):
  cutoff = stand * np.std(array)
  diffs = np.abs(np.diff(array))
  ix = np.where((diffs[:-1] > cutoff) &
                (diffs[1:] > cutoff))[0] + 1
  array[ix] = (array[ix - 1] + array[ix + 1]) / 2.0
  return array
```

Comment: With how I have the code written now, I am taking the average of the two points closest to the discrepant point. This does not work if the discrepant point happens to be the last point in the array, since you can't take the average using a point after the end of the array. So that line compares the value of the array that I am trying to alter to the last element of the array to see if they are the same, and if so, takes the average in a different way. Thank you for the np.where tip, I'll try that out and see if it helps!